# classic asp recordset permissions problem

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, database-permissions

I'm trying to return values of a specific column using the below sql string, If I change it out to `sql = "select * from a_page"` and `objRS("P_description")` it returns the values but for some reason my page will not load when using the below code.

UPDATE: I turned off on error resume next and the error I'm receiving is *select permission denied*. How would I give myself permissions with the code below?

```
SQL = "select P_Name as P_Name, P_Description as P_Description from L_PagePermission inner join A_Permission on p_permissionID = pp_PermissionID inner join A_Page on P_PageID = PP_PageID where P_PageID = 84 order by p_Name"

Page_ID = 84

connectionstring = obj_ADO.getconnectionstring

Set objCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objCon.Open connectionstring

SQL = "select P_Name as P_Name, P_Description as P_Description from L_PagePermission inner join A_Permission on p_permissionID = pp_PermissionID inner join A_Page on P_PageID = PP_PageID where P_PageID = 84 order by p_Name"

objRS.open SQL, objCon

objRS.MoveFirst
while not objRS.EOF
    response.Write objRS("P_Name")
    objRS.MoveNext
wend

objRS.close
objCon.close
```

Comment: Question 1: Do the values of P_Description contain special characters such as <, >, &, which may be interpreted as HTML? Question 2: Do you use "On Error Resume Next" in your script? If yes, you might get better error messages if you comment that line out.

Comment: p_description does contain underscores in it but thats it

Comment: I removed the on error resume next and the error I'm receiving is   ]SELECT permission denied on object 'A_Permission', database. Thanks that on error resume next was a huge problem

Comment: What database type are you using? And what does the connection string look like (with the actual u/p, and server name redacted natch.)

Comment: Its Microsoft sql server with a connection string that looks simlar to this "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=xxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;Data Source=xxxx"

Comment: Not exactly I'm not at work experience ATM so that's what I remember it looked like

Comment: What exact line is causing the error and what is the exact error message?

Comment: Please notify with `@` when you reply to comments e.g. @namehere otherwise people won't see you replied and won't come back.

Comment: @ShadowWizard the line that is causing the error is SQL = "select P_Name as P_Name, P_Description as P_Description from L_PagePermission inner join A_Permission on p_permissionID = pp_PermissionID inner join A_Page on P_PageID = PP_PageID where P_PageID = 84 order by p_Name", the error message was select permission denied I cant tell you the exact message until the next time I go into the office in a few days unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get plus the code you mentioned that is working means one thing: on either `L_PagePermission` table or `A_Permission` (or both) the user passed in the connection string has no Read permissions.

To solve this, you have to either pass "stronger" user in the connection string, or grant Read permissions to the user over those tables via something like SQL Management Studio.

By the way, you can't "grant yourself permissions" through code due to obvious security reasons - permissions exist to prevent code from doing certain things in the first place.